# Proof about n x n matrices and determinants

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove.

Let $X$ and $P $ be $n \times n $ matrices with $P$ invertible; let $A = PXP^{-1}$.

Then, det $A =$ det $X$, and $A^3 = PX^3P^{-1}$.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: $A^3=(PXP^{-1})(PXP^{-1})(PXP^{-1})=?$

Comment: $X$ and $A$ are [similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity) matrices

Answer (score 0):

**Hint for det $A$= det $X$:**

The determinant of a product is the product of the determinants.

**Hint for $A^3=PX^3P^{-1}$:**

$A^3=(PXP^{-1})(PXP^{-1})(PXP^{-1})$.  Use the associative property and note $P^{-1}PX=IX=X$.